# Changing the default page based on security group in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

We have a SharePoint site collection. In this site collection we have a home site and 6 other sites. Each of these sites belongs to a department in our company. Right now if you are a member of department A security group you would see homepage and your department site/tab when you navigate to the site. What they want me to do is to redirect the users directly to the department site/tab whenever they navigate to the site.

Is there any way to do this without coding or with coding?

Comment: I think this would be better answered from the sysadmin community on serverfault :)

Answer (score 0):

With coding, you could write a very simple web control and include that on the home page. It would test which group a user belongs to and then [redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirect.aspx) accordingly.

There are various ways to check if a user belongs to a group. One method is to get a reference to each [SPGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.aspx) object and use [SPGroup.ContainsCurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.containscurrentuser.aspx).

You might also like to consider creating a custom list that maps SPGroup name against department URL, so you can manage behaviour of the control through the SharePoint UI.